# SWT Shell no taskbar icon

Tags: java, swt, taskbar

Can I hide shell icon from taskbar **without** using style `SWT.ON_TOP`? I have to hide it but it can't be over all applications.

Comment: Why do you have to hide it?

Comment: It may be not the best way, but I am trying to use semi transparent shells to imitate shadow and tt looks fine, but all those "shell-shadows" are displayed in the taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

From [a similar question on Eclipsezone](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t75726.html)

> Try creating a shell and not calling setVisible() or open() on it. Next
>   create another shell (the dialog) with hidden shell as a parent.